# SonarQube analysis issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, java-8, sonarqube

I am getting below error while building project with `Sonarqube`:

```
The following errors occurred during analysis:
  Exception analyzing com.org.client.employee.EmployeeClient using detector com.h3xstream.findsecbugs.spring.SpringEntityLeakDetector
  java.lang.NullPointerException
  At com.h3xstream.findsecbugs.spring.SpringEntityLeakDetector.analyzeMethod(SpringEntityLeakDetector.java:107)
  At com.h3xstream.findsecbugs.spring.SpringEntityLeakDetector.visitClassContext(SpringEntityLeakDetector.java:68)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.DetectorToDetector2Adapter.visitClass(DetectorToDetector2Adapter.java:76)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.analyzeApplication(FindBugs2.java:1080)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:281)
  At org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:235)
  At java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  At java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am trying to exclude `client` directory from sonar coverage but looks like `exclusion` is not working:

```
property "sonar.coverage.exclusions", "**/client/**"
```

Below are the version I am using:

```
SonarQube - 7.9
Gradle - 4.9
Spring Boot - 2.1.3
Java - Jdk8
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax to ignore the whole `client` package is:

```
**/client/**/*
```

Read more at the documentation for SonarQube 7.9 [Narrowing the Focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.9/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/).